# How do i convert a .dat file to .zip in qliksense

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

I am new to QlikSense, and I want a file to be converted into `zip` format.

For Ex. File .dat file present at location `C:/MyLocation/ABC.dat` is expected to get converted into `C:/MyLocation/ABC.zip`.

kindly help with the solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

QlikSense itself can't directly zip files up. However using batch files and PowerShell scripts can zip a file up, and you can schedule this to be either a time-related Schedule or a data-related one within QlikSense Management Services.

Comment: thank you for the response. Do i have to explicitely install any switch ex. 7zip or winRaR

Comment: @Aieshwaryathakur No problem! There is no specific one you need, however you can use the following code to do this with 7zip in a batch file: `
@ECHO ON

SET SourceDir=C:\folder\source
SET DestDir=C:\folder\destination

CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%"') DO (
    7z.exe a "%DestDir%\%%~NF.zip" "%SourceDir%\%%~NXF"
)
EXIT`

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Qlik cant convert files. It just reads them.

You'll have to use something else to convert it (like `PowerShell`)